# I am learning java and i want java program in a particular issue

Tags: java

i want to create java program for a number when divided by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 leaves a remainder of 1 but it is divided by 7 completely.
I tried this logic

```
for (int a=1;a<=500;a++){
 if (a%2==1 && a%3==1 && a%4==1 && a%5==1 && a%6==1 && a%7==0)
```

and it works fine but I want it by this logic

```
for (int a=1;a<=500;a++){
for(int b=2;b<=6; b++){


 if (a%b==1 && a%7==0){
System.out.println(a);
```

help me if it is possible to create in this way?Thank you

Comment: That code seems fine. Are you getting any error?

Comment: My 2 cents : `a=0;a<=500;a+=7` would be better in the for loop :).

Answer (score 1):

You could count how many of the iterations pass your test, like this:

```
for (int a=1;  a<=500;  a++) {
    int flag=0;
    for (int b=2;  b<=6;  b++) {
        if (a%b == 1) {
            flag += 1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 5) {
        if (a%7 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Value "+a);
        }
    }
}
```

If any of the tests fail, `flag` will be less than 5 at the end of the loop.  If you change the number of tests, you will need to remember to update that magic number.

Answer (score 0):

you could name the outer loop and check and continue it in the inner loop like this:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    // That´s your mainloop
    mainLoop: for (int a=1; a<=500; a++){
        for(int b=2; b<7;++b) {
            // If anything doesn´t leave a remainder of 1 youll continue with the mainloop here
            if(a%b != 1) {
                continue mainLoop;
            }
        }
        // 2-6 had a remainder of 1, so just check if the number is dividible by 7 now, if so print it.
        if(a%7 ==0) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can make things easier if you split your code into functions.  Start with the outer (`a`) loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (int a = 1;  a <= 5000;  ++a)
        if (test(a))
            System.out.println(a);
}
```

We've deferred the actual logic to the `test()` function, and assumed we'll define that later.

Now write the test.  As soon as any of the sub-tests fail, we can return false immediately.  If all tests pass and we reach the end, then we must return true:

```
static boolean test(int x)
{
    // i is the candidate factor
    for (int i = 2;  i <= 7;  ++i) {
        int expected = i==7 ? 0 : 1;
        if (x%i != expected)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

We can simplify further through use of a magic number to encode the different values of `expected`:

```
static boolean test(int x)
{
    for (int i = 2;  i <= 7;  ++i)
        if (x%i != 301%i)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over all the `b` values, and set a flag if any of them fail the test.  If the flag is unset at the end of the loop, you know they all passed:

```
for (int a=1; a<=500; a++) {
    int flag = 0;
    for (int b=2; b<=6; b++) {
        if (a%b!=1 || a%7!=0) {
            // doesn't satisfy the condition, so flag it
            flag = 1;
            break; // exit the inner loop
        }
    }
    if (flag == 0)
        // If we got here without setting flag, it means that all of the
        // 'b' values passed the test.
        System.out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: should be && place of ||

Comment: no. it should be OR condition only.. a%b should not be 1 or a%7 s'not be 0.. this is the opp condition of (a%b ==1 and a%7 ==0) .

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @TobySpeight : Done...  :)

Comment: That's not what I mean (and not really how anyone should use comments).  Can you explain what your answer does differently to the code in the question?  As I see it, it's down to keeping a record in the `flag` variable.  I'll try an edit to show what I mean.

Comment: I've edited to explain the idea as well as the implementation.